# Prestashop 1.7 unable to load template during import

Tags: import, prestashop

I've got fresh Presta 1.7 installation. I'm importing my data, valid data, but I'm getting an error An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to load template 'file:layout-ajax.tpl'"). I have never seen anything like this.

Any ideas please?

[full error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcHKh.jpg)

Comment: It is version 1.7.4.2, just checked on my localhost - the same problem in here :(

Comment: Same Problem on 1.7.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Please delete cache manually by deleting all folder `(dev and prod)` in `var/cache` folder.

Comment: Os? linux or windows?

Comment: i have got linux

Comment: Can you please check that you are having all permissions ok? folder should have `755` and files should have `644` permission.